# Visual Studio UnitTest, как установить порядок исполнения тестов?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте.

Создал класс юнит тестов, в котором есть 3 метода, но получается так что они запускаются в неправильном порядке, на скрине указал проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Модульные тесты должны быть такими, чтобы не было зависимости от порядка их выполнения Если вы хотите, чтобы некоторая часть кода выполнялась перед каждым тестом - установите атрибут `SetUp` и после - `TearDown`. Также есть атрибуты, которые указывают, что метод должен выполняться перед/после _всех_ тестов - `OneTimeSetUp` и `OneTimeTearDown` . Примеры привел для `NUnit`, так как вы не уточнили что используете.

Comment: В `MSTest` есть атрибуты `[TestInitialize], [TestCleanup]` и порядок можно устанавливать через `[Priority(0)]`

Comment: Спасибо большое.